# Как запустить python script в терминале linux используя python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ос

Доброе утро. У меня есть программа на python:

```py
import subprocess
import os


if os.name == 'nt':
    cmd = ["python", 'code_result.py']
else:
    cmd = [r"python3", 'code_result.py']


print('\n* Compiling python script...')
raw_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
output = raw_output.decode('utf-8')
print(output)
```

Когда я запускаю код в терминале Windows, всё работает. Когда я запускаю этот же код в терминале Linux, просто запускается интерпретатор Python, я ввожу `exit()` и выводится пустая строка в качестве результата. Вопрос: "Как мне получить результат выполнения файла `code_result.py` в терминале Linux?"

Возможно, это как-то связано с тем, что я использую WSL 2 (подсистему Linux в Windows), а не настоящий Linux терминал, но думаю, это мало вероятно.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` в начале скрипта и `python3 code_result.py`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: shell=True потому что)